# Instantiate a class outside of jar file in java?

Tags: java

Is it possible to load a class outside the jar file.

- Janibot // Main Directory

  - lib // sub directory

    - Robot.java
    - Robot.class
  - Janibot.jar // sub directory

above is the structure of directory. I want to do is to instantiate a Robot class when I run the Janibot.jar using Class.forName but it always return a classnotfoundexception.

my plan is to edit the Robot.java in a JtextArea and compile it at runtime and then instantiate a Robot.class

Comment: Can you not include the other Jar as a library? This would be a much cleaner solution.

Comment: @christopher no sir, because my plan is to edit the Robot.java in a JtextArea and compile it at runtime then calling the Robot.class

Comment: Not sure if that will work.  If the Robot.class file does not exist when the JVM is launched, it may not be picked up later.

Comment: @EJK - Even if it is created after the JVM starts, and in a path that is not in the classpath, it can still be loaded with a custom class loader.

Comment: @EJK how? can you please provide an example?

Comment: That comment was actually made by Hot Licks.  I have never built a custom class loader before.  A quick Google search (and stack overflow) shows that there is plenty of information out there.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as long as you are using standard Java*, then where a class is deployed (jar file, loose class) does not matter.  What does matter is that you launch your application with all relevant class directories and jar files on the class path.

Assuming you are in the root directory of the project (Janibot), the following java command will accomplish this:

```
java -classpath ./lib:./janibot.jar  <class_to_execute>
```

(* OSGI would be an exception to this.  OSGI uses a different class loader with a different set of rules, but I assume that is is not in the picture here)